# Extracting Characters from Folder Path in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a huge list of folder paths as text in an Excel worksheet from which I would like to extract the number after each backslash. These numbers then need compiling into a shortened reference. For example:

Original link (let's say in cell A1):

```
c:\1_Folder\2_Folder\3_Folder
```

Shortened reference (desired outcome):

```
1.2.3
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think this is possible using a formula. If it requires the use of VBA, this is far beyond my skills currently.

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Are you saying `c:\1_Folder\2_Folder\3_Folder` exists as a field? EG, `A1` value is `c:\1_Folder\2_Folder\3_Folder` ?

Comment: you are correct - apologies for not including it in the initial question. (Should I edit the question? Is this the correct etiquette?)

Comment: yes BobJim,  usually it's fine to edit your question to add as much detail as you can to ensure the question is as clear as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This VBA will do what you want. Please note, my example only looked from cell `A1` to cell `A10` - you need to update that to reflect what you need (the cell range)!

In case you don't know how to do this, add the developer to the ribbon. In the controls, click insert and add a button. Add a new macro. Insert the following inside the sub routine...

```
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Cells 'UPDATE THIS ROW ONLY WITH THE RANGE YOU WANT TO USE. This loops through all the cells in the range
        Dim resultsString As String
        resultsString = ""
        Dim splitString() As String
        splitString = Split(c, "\") ' split the value of the current cell by \

        For Each v In splitString
            If v <> "" Then 'only check those with a value
                Dim numberOfDigits As Integer
                numberOfDigits = 0
                For charCount = 1 To Len(v)
                    If IsNumeric(Left(v, charCount)) Then
                        numberOfDigits = charCount ' read how many characters there are (which are numbers)
                    End If
                Next

                If (numberOfDigits > 0) Then
                    resultsString = resultsString & Left(v, numberOfDigits) & "." 'if there are numbers, then read that number of digits from the left
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Dim iLength As Integer
        iLength = Len(resultsString)
        If (iLength > 0) Then ' if there are any values
            Range("B" & i).Value = Left(resultsString, iLength - 1) 'UPDATE THIS ROW ONLY IF YOU WANT TO USE A DIFFERENT COLUMN THAN B TO SHOW RESULTS. This takes the value - 1 character (sicne the last character is a .
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next
```

I've added a screen of the results

[image]

Comment: Thank you dave, I was OK getting the Sub Procedure into a module and assigned to the Button.

Comment: Cool - I wasn't being rude going into that detail, but your post said VBA beyond your skills so I thought it best to give too much detail than too little (plus it may help others) :)

Comment: Not taken that way at all, thank you for your guidance! How did you create the script so quickly though!

Comment: I'm a developer so I'm fairly used to it (although the code could be cleaner it should suffice fine for your needs)

Comment: How difficult would it be for the script to only output a string of numbers and full stops? My reason is because the path is sometimes like this **c:\My_Folders\1_Folder\2_Folder\3_Folder**. Is it possible the script could output just 1.2.3? Or is that a huge modification?

Comment: @BobJim , I've made an update, and updated the image. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Raystafarian, yes, I'm sure the code could be refactored quite a bit, it's a little hacky but, for the end result it won't matter!

Comment: Dave, thanks for the update, it took me a while to workout which part to replace and where. Unfortunately I have come across an issue which we won't be able to work around. Some of the folder numbers are greater than 9 (so two digits long) and in other cases people have made single digits two characters long by adding a preceding zero (e.g. 03) :(

Comment: @BobJim yeah you'll need to modify the code to look at the character after the character already pulled to see if it's numeric..

Comment: That is above my skills!

Comment: @BobJim, see the new edit and screen shot

Comment: @Dave Rook thanks for your help today, my mission is to now fully understand your code!

Comment: @BobJim - Good luck, it's not the neatest code ever. I've added some comments which may help

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to data - text to columns
2. Delimit based on the `\`
3. Then you can use a formula like `=LEFT(A2,1)&"."&LEFT(B2,1)&"."&LEFT(C2,1)`

---

VBA - assuming your data is in column A

```
Sub Search_DelimitedSubString_In_String()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
j = 1
'Loop through cells
For Each c In Range("A:A")
    'Select non-blanks
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)
            If Mid(c.Value, i, 1) = "\" Then
                If IsNumeric(Mid(c.Value, i + 1, 1)) Then
                strFolder = strFolder & Mid(c.Value, i + 1, 1) & "."
                End If
            End If

        Next

    Cells(j, 2) = strFolder
    j = j + 1
    End If
 strFolder = ""
 Next c

 For Each c In Range("B:B")
 If c.Value <> "" Then
    k = Len(c.Value)
    c.Value = Left(c.Value, k - 1)
 End If
 Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is quite manual operation for 158K folder paths. As the formula you have suggested would need to be updated as the numbers of columns produced by the Delimit function varies hugely. Thanks for the initial idea though.

Comment: So you do or do not want VBA?

Comment: VBA will be fine if only minor edits are required regarding the range of cells it should process. I didn't specify VBA as I wanted to explore the formula based options first, prior to creating a VBA tool.

Comment: I put in my version of VBA, looking only for numbers following \

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.. The results concatenate. You need to add `strFolder = ""` after `For Each c In Range("A:A")`

Comment: @DaveRook good call. I could also clean it up a bit to count the data and then write it appropriately. This won't work for any non-contiguous ranges in A:A as it won't skip a `j` if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Raystafarian thanks for your help today, my mission is to now fully understand your code!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your data is in column A, then column B would look like:

[image]

```
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
RE.Global = True
RE.Pattern = "\\(\d+)"

For Each c In UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
    Set matches = RE.Execute(c)
    ReDim all(matches.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        all(i) = matches.Item(i).Submatches(0)
    Next
    c.Offset(0, 1) = Join(all(), ".")
Next
```

I used VBA Regex, two loops and an array Join

VBA RegEx [doesn't supported lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150552/lookbehind-on-regex-for-vba) or else you could use `(?<=\\)\d+`.

Comment: Can you use capture groups in VBA? I think that'd make things a little simpler.

Comment: @Jerry You mean a non-capturing group like my edit? (Feel free to suggest a better pattern)

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with Excel's regexes, but you should be able to get the value of `(\d+)` directly. I did a search and I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904299/1578604) is a nice example (although the regex might be a little complex. You don't need the non-capture group, so just having `"\\(\d+)"` should work.

Comment: @Jerry This is short enough for me. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

is it important to use vba?
**if you are using version 2013 of Excel** its so much easier to use "Flash Fill" feature to do that...

Flash Fill is a feature to fill the cells by the pattern of the cells next to them:

just fill the A1, A2, A3,... with the strings you want to extract chars from,
fill the B1 as the way you want answer:

[image]

in B2 press CTRL + E, excel will fill other cells as you want:

[image]

Comment: Care to elaborate what 'Flash Fill' is? Otherwise, I don't think this would qualify as an answer =/

Comment: @Jerry, more details added... can you tell me why my answer does not qualify as an answer? where im wrong? (just want to know my mistake to prevent repeating it again)

Comment: Just saying that using 'Flash Fill' doesn't qualify as an answer. It's like answering to the question 'How do I get the first 1000 prime numbers?' and replying 'Use Sieve of Eratosthenes'. Now, if the user has never heard of it they would be just as clueless as they would have been when asking the question. Also, it might be worth noting that Flash Fill is available only in Excel-2013 as of now and you don't know what excel version the OP is using.

Answer (score -1):

If "Folder" is really "Folder" (and not a common name for special folder names), then this formula will be the fastest. Enter it into B1 and drag it down or click twice on the filling plus:

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_Folder\","."),"c:\",""),"_Folder","")